# Bottom menu bar in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am developing an application for Android and am having a bit of trouble formatting my bottom menu bar.  I provided the relevant code for the menu bar with a picture of how it is rendering as well as a picture of how I would like it to be displayed.

It seems as if my views are being centered even when I set android:layout_gravity to left or right.  I have also tried android:gravity and have the same outcome.

**Should I be using padding instead of the nested weights?**

**What I have:**
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/607/have.png/

**What I want:** 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/600/wantb.png/

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000"
    android:weightSum="25"> 
/*
 *other layouts
*/

//layout for bottom menu bar
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/menubar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/iv_previous"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/left_trans"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
    <ImageView
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/iv_multi"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/multi_trans"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/iv_search"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/search_trans"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/iv_pen"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pen_trans"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/iv_highlighter"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/highlighter_trans"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/iv_tag"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/tag_trans"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/iv_next"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/right_trans"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT** (Using RelativeLayout --> not working):

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/menubar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/iv_previous"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/left_trans"
        />
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_next"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/right_trans"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_multi"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_previous"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/multi_trans"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_search"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_multi"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/search_trans"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_tag"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv_next"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/tag_trans"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_highlighter"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv_tag"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/highlighter_trans"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_pen"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv_highlighter"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pen_trans"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you forget the pictures, or are they just not displaying for me?

Comment: Just wondering, why not relative layout. It would fit your need so much better in this case?

Comment: sorry, just added the links to the pictures.

Comment: @roostertech I just tried to implement it as a relative layout and the menu displayed nothing. I put the iv_previous and iv_next as             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" and             android:layout_alignParentRight="true" respectively. I then used              android:layout_toRightOf="..." and             android:layout_toLeftOf="..." depending on where I wanted to place the views.

Comment: Change the layout width for the relative layout to wrap_content